# How to find a used car with telescoping steering wheel?

Tags: steering-wheel

I need a car with adjustable steering wheel distance.

I need to pull the seat all the way back and if I do so, my arms are straight.

It makes driving very uncomfortable.

People selling them are not usually listing this feature.

Is there a way to find which models have this as a standard/option?

Comment: The term you're looking for is reach adjustment. Search for your car of choice online, then in the details secion, see if it mentions steering reach adjustment. (rake adjustment means up and down, reach means in and out).

Comment: @JuannStrauss - Also goes by - Tilt and Telescopic. Tilt - Up and Down, and Telescopic - In and Out –

Answer (score 1):

I believe you really have three options I can think of:

1. Put your Google-Fu to use and scour the internet. I used the phrase [cars with telescoping steering wheels](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=cars%20with%20telescoping%20steering%20wheels) in my search and came up with two lists which might be helpful:

   - [Top 10 Vehicles for Shorter Drivers](http://www.carmax.com/enus/top-10-lists/top-10-vehicles-for-shorter-drivers.html)
   - [Top 10 Vehicles for Taller Drivers](http://www.edmunds.com/car-reviews/top-10/top-10-vehicles-for-taller-drivers.html)

While you may think that is cray-cray or something, there are vehicles on there shown to have telescoping steering wheels.

2. Your second bet is to get one installed after you find a vehicle you like. There is a company called [**ididit**](http://www.ididitinc.com/). They are out of Michigan. They have universal telescoping steering wheels which will retro-fit into anything ... if you find a qualified mechanic to put it in. I would imagine there are plenty of companies out there that make such steering wheels. I know the quality of the ididit ones are among the best. I had chance to visit their factory about five years ago. They are top notch.
3. Another choice may be not looking for the steering wheel as that, but look instead for vehicles which have adjustable pedals. I owned an '04 Chevrolet Suburban Z71 which had these. The pedals would adjust downward towards the floor for taller people, or towards the driver for shorter. In your case, you are wanting to sit further away from the steering wheel, so you'd probably put the seat a bit further back and extend the pedals along with it. It is really pretty slick. I'm sure the Suburban is not the only vehicle out there with them.